# iTunes notifications

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard, notifications

I'd like to have a notification displayed in the dock every time a new song is played. Unfortunately, this doesn't exist as an option in the program preferences, but there are ways to do it, see [this article](http://www.yourdailymac.net/2011/11/how-to-activate-the-hidden-notification-system-in-mac-os-x-lion/) for example.

However, for some reason this doesn't work for me. Can you guess why? I'm using a MacBook Pro with iTunes 10.6.1 running on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: I think this is because your link is a tip for Mac OS Lion (10.7) and you're using Snow Leopard (10.6).

Answer (score 2):

This tweak is for OSX 10.7 only.

For something equivalent in OSX 10.6, you might want to give a try with 3rd party notifiers. The ones that come in mind right now are:

- [Growl](http://growl.info/) (my personal favorite)
- [Sizzling Keys](http://www.yellowmug.com/sk4it/)

There surely are more notification apps out there, Google is your friend!